# KnockoutJs ko.utils.arrayForEach

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to get my head around Knockout and came across this scenario.

Why wouldn't this work??

Computing using: ko.utils.arrayForEach

http://jsfiddle.net/pradeepdhi/vX88g/

*the moment it remove the following, it renders without any errors (but ofcourse doesn't give the total as well)

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.children(), function(item) {
        total += parseFloat(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item.age));
    });
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with your `this` scope.

Check this [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vX88g/1/)

OR

```
this.totalAge = ko.computed(function() {
        var total = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.children(), function(item) {
            total += parseFloat(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item.age));
        });
        return total;
}, this);
```

From ko [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html):

> In case you’re wondering what the second parameter to ko.computed is (the bit where we passed this in the preceding code), that defines the value of this when evaluating the computed observable. Without passing it in, it would not have been possible to refer to this.children() [ *in your case* ].

Comment: Cheers for your prompt reply. I guess including something like 'var self = this;" as the first line inside the viewmodel and using self.children() would have worked as well. Figured it out just after posting the query. Many thanks anyways.